# Definitive guide to threads, processes and lwp

Tags: multithreading

I know the difference between a thread and a process. But while reading `Operating System Principles` by `Galvin`, I came across `LWP (lightweight process)`. While Galvin defines it as a virtual process, some other sources say that it is basically a thread.

Due to reading from various sources I have now similar confusion about fibers and threading models. My question is:

```
1. What exactly is a LWP?
2. What role does LWP plays in different threading models 
   (one-to-one, many-to-one etc)
3. Some idea on how LWP are implemented
4. What is a fiber? Is it a generic term or related to some specific OS/library?
```

Also about threading models, how are they scheduled? Is threading library routine is scheduling threads in user-space or is kernel is doing the scheduling.

Essentially, I am hoping for a detailed answer which explains various terms related to multithreading and threading models.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for using lightweight processes is to minimize overhead caused by [context switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).

An easy way to do this is to implement LWPs as threads within the same address space (ie. within one process), which roughly reduces the costs of a process switch to that of a thread switch. If you are looking for trouble, you are usually still able to observe shared memory, given that your programming environment is sufficiently low-level. From a developer's point of view you are merely *pretending* to work with processes (ie. you chose to not use shared memory to exchange data even though you technically could), while from the operating system's point of view your "processes" are essentially threads.

Note that LWPs can be implemented on different levels in the system: Many operating systems offer support for them, but in theory, you could also write a pure user-mode LWP framework in your favorite thread-aware programming language and get cracking.

Since LWPs are basically threads, they in principle support all threading models that kernel threads do on that same operating system. Similarly, the implementation in the operating system is basically based on threads, plus the necessary changes in bookkeeping to make them recognizable as LWPs to the user.

To summarise, LWPs implement the concept of processes on through threads, which allows us to get rid of some context-switching overhead. The tradeoff is that we lose the distinct memory address spaces that the operating system enforces for processes. But as long as we behave ourselves we can just pretend that we are still using real processes. The [Erlang programming language](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/processes.html) is a nice real-world example of this concept.

Fibers do the same trick on a different level: A fiber (which is sort of a light-weight thread) implements the concept of multiple threads through a single thread, which allows us to get rid of thread switching overhead (we stay on the same call stack). The tradeoff here is that we lose preemptive multitasking. That means a fiber has to voluntarily declare that it is ready to stop executing before another fiber can do work.

As with LWPs the concept of fibers can also be implemented in pure user mode without help from the operating system. However, when people talk about fibers they usually refer to the implementation in an OS, while user-mode implementations typically use the term *coroutine* (they really mean the same thing though). Examples for coroutines in the real world are the [Lua programming language](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.2) or the [Boost coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html) library for C++.